# How to unmap an expired or old record in Heroku-Connect?

Tags: heroku, salesforce, heroku-postgres

In my current heroku setup with an salesforce application, I am getting few unwanted records while mapping the avaialable fields from SFDC to Heroku postgres.

I checked currently, those fields are no longer exists in Salesforce. This problem causing issue while syncing between Postgres and SFDC.

Need your help how to deal/delete/unmap those kind of fields in Heorku-Connect addon.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your connect dashboard and click the wrench icon under Mappings:
[image]

Scroll to the bottom of the page and you'll see a button to delete this mapping.

Comment: Sorry the query was to know, how certain unwanted fields to be unmapped(those fields generally come with a red strip over it, and no information for those get listed in the edit mapping page.)

Comment: @All, I got the solution for the issue though these kind of issues not occurs often, but these situations can be resolved with a full reload of a certain mapping.